# income stat question involving standard deviation

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics

despite the outrageous incomes of some, the mean income of all aging rock stars is relatively modest: \$75000 with standard deviation of \$2000. on the scale, Chubby Checker, appears to do better than average: at most only 6.25% of aging rockers make more than he does. What is chubby Checkers income?

I dont understand how to use the standard deviation here, what i did was $\frac{6.25}{100} \times 75000 + 75000 $

can someone explain this to me thanks.

Comment: That is a surprisingly small standard deviation.  Are you using a normal distribution, or Chebyshev's inequality, or something else?